# Why does Open3.popen3 return wrong error when executable is missing?

Tags: ruby, popen3

I'm making a Ruby wrapper around a CLI. And I found a neat method, `Open3.capture3` (which internally uses `Open3.popen3`), which lets me execute commands and captures stdout, stderr and exit code.

One thing that I want to detect is if the CLI executable wasn't found (and raise a special error for that). I know that the UNIX shell gives exit code `127` when command wasn't found. 
And when I execute `$ foo` in bash, I get `-bash: foo: command not found`, which is exactly the error message I want to display.

With all that in mind, I wrote code like this:

```
require "open3"

stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(command)
case status.exitstatus
when 0
  return stdout
when 1, 127
  raise MyError, stderr
end
```

But, when I ran it with `command = "foo"`, I get an error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - foo
  /Users/janko/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:193:in `spawn'
  /Users/janko/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:193:in `popen_run'
  /Users/janko/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:93:in `popen3'
  /Users/janko/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/open3.rb:252:in `capture3'
```

Why does this error occur? I thought `Open3.capture3` was supposed to execute that command directly in the shell, why then don't I get a normal STDERR and exit code of `127`?

Answer (score 10):

`Open3.popen3` delegates to `Kernel.spawn`, which depending on the way the command is passed in, gives the command to shell or directly to OS.

```
commandline                 : command line string which is passed to the standard shell
cmdname, arg1, ...          : command name and one or more arguments (This form does not use the shell. See below for caveats.)
[cmdname, argv0], arg1, ... : command name, argv[0] and zero or more arguments (no shell)
```

We might expect that if we call `Kernel.spawn("foo")`, it would be passed to the shell (and not OS). But it doesn't, documentation for `Kernel.exec` explains why:

```
If the string from the first form (exec("command")) follows these simple rules:

* no meta characters
* no shell reserved word and no special built-in
* Ruby invokes the command directly without shell

You can force shell invocation by adding ";" to the string (because ";" is a meta character).
```

Last paragraph reveals the solution.

```
require "open3"

stdout, stderr, status = Open3.capture3(command + ";")
case status.exitstatus
when 0
  return stdout
when 1, 127
  raise MyError, stderr
end
```

Comment: Old but valid.  My addition if you want to add parameters include them in the command e.g. `Open3.capture3('ld --version' + ';')`, if you want to add it like this it will not work `Open3.capture3('ld', '--version' + ';')` which is the recommended way to add parameters.